# Java program works from the IDE but not the command line

Tags: java, command-line

I've been working a simple program, and when I run it from the IDE it works 100% as intended, but when I try to compile it using javac from the command line it comes up saying with this:

```
C:\Users\Lukasz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NetBeansTest\src\netbeanstest>javac M
ain.java
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
            MainFrame myFrame = new MainFrame();
            ^
  symbol:   class MainFrame
  location: class Main
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
            MainFrame myFrame = new MainFrame();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class MainFrame
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

However I am unsure what could possibly missing as all of the files are in the same directory. This is what my main looks like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            MainFrame myFrame = new MainFrame();
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see it's nothing complicated. Line 19 where the error is `MainFrame myFrame = new MainFrame();` but I do not see what could be wrong with it , as it compiles file in the IDE.

Any help here would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you compile your `MainFrame` class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling `Main.java`, which has a dependency on `MainFrame.java` file.

Try compiling and creating a `.class` file for `MainFrame` before compiling `Main.java`

To compile a directory use :

```
javac dir1/*.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only compiling one file. The compiler hasn't been informed about the existence of the file containing the MainFrame class.

Comment: That would make sense, how would I go about easily compiling everything in the folder?